# Count frequencies of all elements in array

Tags: c

**Problem**: Given an unsorted array of n integers which can contain integers from 1 to n. Some elements can be repeated multiple times and some other elements can be absent from the array. Count frequency of all elements that are present and print the missing elements

**Code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, x, t, n, m;

    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        scanf("%d",&m);
        int b[m];
        int a[m];
        int c[m];

        for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            b[i] = i + 1;
        }
    //  for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        //{
        //  printf("%d ", b[i]);
        //}
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            c[i] = 0;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (b[j] == a[i]) {
                    c[i] = c[i] + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            printf("%d ", c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**: I am getting output as 1 1 1 1 1.Can anybody please point out the logical mistake in my code?

Comment: What is the maximal value of an input? If it's not huge, you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Comment: It will be really helpful if you can point out the mistake in my code.In that way I will be able to learn.

Comment: You talk about integers from 1 to n, and have a variable `int n` but do not use it. Can you please use variables names that are meaningful? It might be a lot of bother while writing the code, but it is easy to search and replace afterwards.

Comment: Sorry for the bad coding,I am just trying to understand the error in my logic.

Comment: Sourav - I'm afraid the algorithm you use is not correct (at least I don't see a clear way how to fix it without rewriting), so, it is a bit premature to talk about mistakes in the *code*. First get a working algorithm idea. Also, turning the code into a [mcve] would help. You're missing some bits - for example, the inputs used to get the output you mention.

Comment: Whitespace is cheap, so there's no reason to suffer without.  Here, though, I've given you some of mine.

Comment: Sir,I have found out the mistake,although it is saying that time required is more than expected,guess I have to optimize it.Thank you anyway.

Comment: You should use better variable names. That helps a lot when reading other peoples code. `a`, `b` and `c` should have better names. Also, neither `x` or `n` is used, so why include it?

Comment: How about doing without array `b` altogether?  It is unnecessary, I assure you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `b` is pretty handy if you want to handle huge numbers.

Comment: @Broman, `b` serves no useful purpose for the problem as presented, even if huge numbers must be handled.  It would make sense only if the specific numbers whose frequencies are to be determined were presented separately and explicitly, in which case such an array would be not only useful but necessary.

Comment: In fact, array `a` isn't necessary either, but at least its use doesn't lead to a needlessly inefficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting your seen number using `i` instead of `j`.

```
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (want[j] == input[i]) {
                seen[i] = seen[i] + 1;  // HERE
            }
        }
    }
```

If you input `2 2 2` then it'll match when `i` is 0. Then it will match when `i` is 1. And it will match when `i` is 2. So you get a 1 in each spot. `i` is the position of the number seen. Instead you want to increment `j`, the number being examined - 1.

```
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (want[j] == input[i]) {
                seen[j] = seen[j] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Which points out a way to make the whole thing much more efficient. `want` is not necessary. Since we want numbers from 1 to n we can use the array index + 1 of `seen`. And you don't need to rescan the whole array each time, `seen` can be built up as you read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int size;
    scanf("%d",&size);

    int seen[size];
    int input;

    // Initialize seen
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        seen[i] = 0;
    }

    // Read input and store how many integers we've seen
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &input);
        seen[input-1] += 1;
    }

    // Print the counts
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d: %d ", i+1, seen[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}
```